# Cleaning up the output of xev

Tags: awk, xev

OS: Openbox session of Lubuntu 14.04

Let's say I run `xev` and press the `Super` key, I get a lot of output (>100 lines) and the relevant information is way down the output as seen when I

- run `xev | grep -in super`
- press `super`
- and then close the `xev` pop-up window.

```
$ xev | grep -in super  
122:    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
129:    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
$
```

I came across a one-liner in the Arch wiki (wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys#In_Xorg) which dramatically cleans up the output (with certain exceptions noted in the link):

```
xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
```

The output is reduced to just:

```
133 Super_L
```

I want to know how the Arch wiki code does its magic. All I can guess is that it's somehow parsing the output starting with `KeyPress` but after that I don't understand anything:

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
root 0x7e, subw 0x0, time 13500391, (362,697), root:(363,760),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
```

Can someone kindly walk through what the code does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
```

- `-F'[ )]+'` tells `awk` to split the line on any number of spaces or brackets. So, the fields in `state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,` would be:

  ```
            # empty field
  state
  0x0,
  keycode
  133
  (keysym 
  0xffeb,
  Super_L
  ,
  same_screen
  YES,
  ```
- `/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] }` creates an empty entry at line number + 2 in the array `a`, for lines beginning with `KeyPress`.
- `NR in a` checks if the current line number has an entry in array `a`. This would be true if a line beginning with `KeyPress` came two lines ago.
- Then it prints the fifth and eighth fields, which are `133` and `Super_L` as can be seen in the first point.

`xev` output actually looks like:

```
$ xev
...
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 217441518, (91,162), root:(91,697),
    state 0x10, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
```

So, for each keypress, the second line after that has the keycode and name.

Comment: So in the field separator, is only `)` enough? That's part of what I didn't understand. Isn't including `(` necessary?

Comment: @DKBose No, there's no particular problem with `(keysym` being a field, since we're not interested in that word. We're only interested in `133` and `Super_L`, so the command uses only as much as it needs to extract those two cleanly.